# Do not count invalid guesses (not numbers or out of range)

Tags: javascript, html

So I am at the last bit of my assessment and have figured out everything I believe. However, the only thing that I am having trouble with is omitting out of range numbers within the tracked guesses. I was able to omit (0 and negative) numbers but I am not sure how to go about omitting numbers that go over the user inputted maximum number. For example, if the user states the maximum number should be 55 and they guess 65. I don't want the guess of 65 to be included in my guesses array. Here is the code I have currently to omit 0 and negative numbers. Any suggestions on alterations to it to omit guesses above the maximum number? Thank you in advance.

```
if(guess == num) {
    message.innerHTML = "BOOM! You got it! It took you " + guessAmount.length + " tries to get it and        the numbers you guessed were " + guessAmount.filter(val => val > 0);
```

Comment: can you include [mcve] of rest of your code

Answer (score 0):

Update the filter condition like so:

```js
.filter(val => val > 0 && val <= MAX_GUESS)
```

Comment: I tried that before and was getting an expression error. I see what error I did. I was getting an error and it is fixed now. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!!! If I could hug you, I would! THANK YOU!

Comment: @Bbrook Well you need to replace `MAX_GUESS` with the actual maximum allowed.

Comment: I had a comma in there thinking that I needed it. Thank you so much. I really appreciate you!